# Remove space around bullet points in itemized or enumerated list

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize, enumerate

How can I reduce the amount of space around items in an itemized or enumerated list?  I would like to reduce the vertical space between items, the space to the left of the bullet, and the space between the bullet and the text.

Comment: Use the `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `paralist` package provides compressed lists, the new environments are called `compactitem`, `compactenum` and `compactdesc`. Use it just like the corresponding standard list environments. It can even keep lists within a paragraph.

The `enumitem` provides more features but also compressed lists, for instance by

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep,leftmargin=*}
```

`\setlist` modifies all lists, `\setitemize` just `itemize` etc. It takes an optional parameter that stands for the level that should be changed, default it alters all levels. Since `enumitem` allows a lot more customization I prefer it over `paralist`, but the latter is easier to use and fits better to the question here.

Comment: AFAIK, the current version of enumitem doesn't support lists within a paragraph.

Comment: That's true, in-para lists are the outstanding paralist feature, the only one that enumitem  doesn't support yet.

Comment: Is there a recommended way to *reduce* the list separation, rather than remove it? I tried `\setlist{itemsep=0pt}`, which works well, but actually only reduces the separation to something half way between the default and `\setlist{nolistsep}`. Why is that?

Comment: I don't think `\setitemize` is  a valid command - you need `\setlist[itemize, <levels>]{<format>}`.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answer provided by [Stefan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/831/183028), we can use the enumitem to create a compact list using the `\setlist{nolistsep}` or parametrizing each component of `\setlist`, as following:

```latex
\setlist{
    topsep=0pt,
    partopsep=0pt,
    itemsep=0pt,
    parsep=0pt
}
```

Where `topsep` and `partopsep` are the vertical space between the list and the paragraphs, `itemsep` is the vertical space between items, and `parsep` is the vertical space between the item's paragraphs.

The below picture, from the [enumitem manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), illustrates each parameter.

[image]

It is worth noticing that we can also change horizontal spacing for a even more compact list.