# Reduce space between enumerated items

Tags: spacing, floats, lists, vertical-alignment, positioning

## Background

All book figures are set to "here definitely" (as they must come after the text that introduces them).

## Problem

The list types (enumerated and bullet) have too much space between them. The reason seems to be because the TeX engine wants to use up as much space on the page as possible, since the next page is essentially a large image that cannot fit on the current page. For example:

[image]

## Related Links

- [Remove space around bullet points in itemized or enumerated list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/825/remove-space-around-bullet-points-in-itemized-or-enumerated-list)
- http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/paralist/paralist.pdf
- http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf

## Question

What can be done to keep the text in lists together (even if it means plenty of space at the bottom of the page)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As "plenty of space at the bottom of the page" seems to be acceptable to you, try to add `\raggedbottom` to your preamble (the default for the book class is `\flushbottom`).

A better solution is not to set every float to "here definitely", but to use `\usepackage{flafter}`. The flafter package ensures that floats won't be typeset before their in-text reference.

Comment: Or just use `[!hbp]` (i.e. don't allow the `t` option which could put the image before the relevant text)

Answer (score 342):

My way of dealing with this situation is the "\itemsep"+length approach:

```
\begin{itemize} 
\itemsep0em 
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{itemize}
```

where "length" can even be a negative value.

Comment: @LondonRob: The only reason I didn't accept this answer was because it felt like mixing presentation with content. Importing a package was simpler than changing all the itemized lists in the document. Adding `\raggedbottom` affected all lists using one line of code.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: Yeah, actually this *is* a good solution, but not *quite* to the problem in the original post! Accepted answer is better for this particular use case. This answer is better for a more general problem of spacing in lists.

Comment: Is there something similar for \begin{enumerate}?

Comment: @ Michael Clerx: for \begin{enumerate} use the very same \itemsep+length approach (this works with any list environment)

Comment: It's cleaner to add it as a parameter: `\begin{itemize}[\itemsep=0em]` etc.

Comment: with `enumitem` and `\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0em]` works for me. Adding a `\` stalls compilation

Answer (score 127):

### "enumitem" package

Using the [`enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=de) package, we can achieve a lot. Not only can we reduce **item separation**, but also we can reduce **list separation**:

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    A normal list:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item one
        \item two
        \item three
    \end{itemize}

    No item separation:
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
        \item one
        \item two
        \item three
    \end{itemize}

    No item and no list separation:
    \setlist{nolistsep}
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
        \item one
        \item two
        \item three
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: output from example]

### Renew commands manually

Or you could renew the `list` commands:

```
\renewcommand{\@listI}{%
\leftmargin=25pt
\rightmargin=0pt
\labelsep=5pt
\labelwidth=20pt
\itemindent=0pt
\listparindent=0pt
\topsep=0pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\partopsep=0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\parsep=0pt plus 1pt
\itemsep=\parsep}
```

**Check also [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061112/eliminate-space-before-beginitemize).**

Comment: good answer. This solution applies to all lists. Using \itemsep0em  requires one to add it to each list. So this solution is much easier actually. I am surprised no one up voted it before.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86055/30201

Comment: `nolistsep` has been replaced by `nosep` according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88990/enumitem-revert-nolistsep/89109#89109

Comment: Can you explain what are all these numbers.... it looks crazy complicated... thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I use `vspace`, gives you full control on the amount of space. I agree that case of long lists general solution like `enumitem` are better.

Code example:

```
    \begin{itemize}
        \vspace{-0.2cm}\item First Line
        \vspace{-0.2cm}\item Second Line 
    \end{itemize}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could try to add a \vfill after your list:

```
\end{enumerate}
\vfill

~
The picture
```

the ~ is needed because space at the end of the page might won't show.

Another way is to explicitly change the page with `\newpage`