# How to have different whitespace BEFORE and AFTER itemize/enumerate globally?

Tags: spacing, enumerate, itemize

This question is heavily inspired by [How to remove the whitespace BEFORE itemize/enumerate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86054/how-to-remove-the-whitespace-before-itemize-enumerate) (thus the name).

From what I understand `topsep` affects both white space before and after the enumerate/itemize. And I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)

I would like to have differing amounts of white space before and after my enumerates/itemize, and preferably do so with a global setting.

Something like `\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt}` would be ideal (if it worked).

Comment: As always on this site: you problably get more help if you provide a minimal example. For example, you'd probably need to mention that you are using `enumitem` which is not clear until one take a closer look at our links

Comment: You can create a custom itemize environment which sets \topsep=0pt and adds its own \vspace before and after.  IIRC, that is how amsmath does equations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LaTeX's lists are expressly designed to have the same amount of vertical spacing before and after. That is coded deep in LaTeX's bowels in the \@trivlist macro. So changing that would require that macro to be adapted, which enumitem doesn't. I think it would have been sensible to both have \topsep and \botsep but apparently Leslie lamport didn't think so.

However, with the `enumitem` package you can insert text before and after the `itemize`, and if you set `topsep=0pt` and insert your own `\vspace` before and after you get basically what you want. And then with `\setlist` you can make these settings global if you want, or just apply them individually, or define your own list type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Text before the itemize.
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,before=\vspace{1cm},after=\vspace{1mm}]
\item An item
\end{itemize}
Text after itemize.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the relevant length (`\@topsepadd`) in the `after` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Text before the itemize.
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0cm,after={\advance\csname @topsepadd\endcsname by1cm}]
\item An item
\end{itemize}
Text after itemize.
\end{document}
```

[image]