# compact bulleted points in table

Tags: tables, itemize

Here is the table I am trying to create, which contains the

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
     \newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}}



         \begin{document}
         \begin{table*}
            \caption{My table caption}
            \label{tab:Table1}
              \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}TX@{}}
               \toprule
                 Column1 & Case of Column2\\
                \midrule
                 column 1 value & 
                  \begin{itemize}
                  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
                  \item multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text
                  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
                  \item multiline item text multiline item text
                  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
                  \end{itemize}  \\
               \bottomrule
              \end{tabularx}
              \end{table*}
             \end{document}
```

Although this is not an elegant solution it eliminates the space before, after and between the bullet points regardless of the spacing scheme in rest of the document. Since the item text itself is multiline text the line spacing is a lot.

Can anyone suggest an elegant solution to create a very compact bulleted points within a table cell. I experimented with the solution given here
       [How to remove the whitespace BEFORE itemize/enumerate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86054/how-to-remove-the-whitespace-before-itemize-enumerate)

Comment: The question you link to uses `\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]` (make sure to add `\usepackage{enumitem}`). Does that not do the trick?

Comment: Also, your code fragment can't be compiled because it misses `\documentclass[]{}` and `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}`.

Comment: thanks @HenkMetselaar when I use \begin{itemize}[noitemsep] the compilation stops with the following message

Package enumitem Error: (1) undefined.

See the enumitem package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.253 \begin{enumerate}[(1)]

and when I press enter it continues to compile.

Comment: Please do not post code fragments, but always minimal compilable code samples (MWE) to help us help you.

Comment: @TeXnician i have edited the code and now its MWE. Can you please suggest the workaround to my issue??

Answer (score 12):

You may achieve your formatting objective by (a) loading the `enumitem` package and using some of its capabilities -- specifically, setting the options `nosep`, `wide=0pt`, `leftmargin=*`, and `after=\strut` -- and (b) encasing the `itemize environment inside a`minipage` environment.

Aside: If the `itemize` environment were *not* contained in a table column, setting the option `nosep` would suffice to suppress the whitespace space padding above and below the `itemize` environment (as well as the whitespace *between* the items). However, because the `itemize` environment occurs inside the column of a `tabularx` environment, it turns out to be necessary to embed the `itemize` environment in a `minipage` environment.

Finally, in case you're curious to find out what the option `after=\strut` does: It ensures that the bottom row of the itemize environment isn't too close to the horizontal line drawn by `\bottomrule`. Note that in your example, the final item row contains no words with characters with descenders (such as `g`, `p`, `q`, and `y`). Without the `\strut`, the material in the bottom line of the `itemize` environment would simply look to be too close to the line drawn by `\bottomrule`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,enumitem,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{My table caption}
\label{tab:Table1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lY @{}}
   \toprule
   Column1 & Column2\\
   \midrule
   column 1 value & 
   \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
   \begin{itemize}[nosep, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, after=\strut]
   \item multiline item text multiline item text multiline    
         item text multiline item text multiline item text
   \item multiline item text multiline item text
   \end{itemize}  
   \end{minipage}\\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the place of  `\leftmargini=10pt`, it would be simpler to add the options `[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]`.

Comment: @Bernard - Excellent suggestion! :-) I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: You made a small mistake: `wide` alone adds an indent (of 1em, I believe) before the bullet. It should be `wide=0pt` to align the bullet with the `C` above.

Comment: @Bernard - I get the exact same alignment with `wide` and `wide=0pt`. Put differently, I notice no extra indent (of 1em or whatever) before the bullet in case I just specify `wide`.

Comment: @Bernard - The fact that we're also specifying `leftmargin=*` may or may not be relevant here -- I'm not sure how, though.

Comment: Strange… Testing on thebasis of your code, I've just discovered it is specific to thetable environment. I rember having to specify `0pt` a few years ago. Maybe something has changed in the code of enumitem? In any case, outside of  tabular, you have to specify it.

Comment: `leftmargin=*` is for having a hanging text of the items.

Comment: @Bernard - Many thanks for looking into the `wide` matter some more. To play it safe -- and to keep future readers of this answer from getting confused -- I'll edit the answer to change `wide` to `wide=0pt`. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Set the list using a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} T X @{} }
  \toprule
  Column1 & Case of Column2 \\
  \midrule
  column 1 value & 
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\textbullet}} p{\dimexpr\linewidth-1.5em} @{} }
    multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text \\
    multiline item text multiline item text
  \end{tabular} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The inner-`tabular` is set similar to a list, spreading the full `\linewidth` of the outer-`tabularx` `X`-column and is `[t]`op-aligned to ensure it aligns vertically with the surrounding cell entries.

Adjust the width for the `\makebox` to change the bullet alignment.

---

For an enumerated list of items, you can use the regular `enumi` counter (for the first level of enumeration inside an `enumerate` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}}

\newcommand{\settabenum}{\makebox[1.5em][l]{%
  \refstepcounter{enumi}%
  \xdef\@currentlabel{\@currentlabel}%
  \theenumi.}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} T X @{} }
  \toprule
  Column1 & Case of Column2 \\
  \midrule
  column 1 value & \setcounter{enumi}{0}% Reset the enumeration counter, if needed
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{\settabenum} p{\dimexpr\linewidth-1.5em} @{} }
    multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text \\
    multiline item text multiline item text
  \end{tabular} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

In the above example there is no need to `\setcounter{enumi}{0}`, but if you have other `enumerate` lists in your document, you may have to reset this within your `tabular`.

If you want to be able to reference some of the items, then we have to use a different setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}}

\newcommand{\settabenum}{%
  \refstepcounter{enumi}%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[1.5em][l]{%
  \theenumi.}}}

\begin{document}

See item~\ref{second}.

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ @{} T X @{} }
  \toprule
  Column1 & Case of Column2 \\
  \midrule
  column 1 value & \setcounter{enumi}{0}% Reset the enumeration counter, if needed
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{\hspace{1.5em}} >{\settabenum} p{\dimexpr\linewidth-1.5em} @{} }
    multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text \\
    multiline item text multiline item text \label{second}
  \end{tabular} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Werner Thanks a lot for the solution. This is what i exactly needed. :)

Comment: hi  @Werner I really like your solution. What if i need an ordered list? Will it be a minor change in the code?

Comment: @Prem: See my updated answer.