# Create a comparison type table where multiple line and bullet points exists

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx, bullets

I want to create a table like the following picture [image]

I tried with this code basically from this post
[compact bulleted points in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406116/compact-bulleted-points-in-table)

```
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5.354cm}}
\begin{table*}
\caption{The table caption}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|T|T|T|}
\hline
Column 1 & Column2 & Column 3\\
\hline
Multiple column and column & 
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\textbullet}} 
   p{\dimexpr\linewidth-1.5em} @{} }
multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item 
  text multiline item text \\
multiline item text multiline item text
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}[t]{ @{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\textbullet}} p{\dimexpr\linewidth- 
1.5em} @{} }
multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item 
 text multiline item text \\
multiline item text multiline item text
\end{tabular} \\
\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

The result is 
[image]
But the problem is that there is some unnecessary space in the first column. I am not expert in latex. Is there any convenient and efficient way to make this type of table in latex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You are setting the width of all columns, including the first one, explicitly. You could just choose a smaller width for the first column if you do not want to waste space.

Comment: welcome to tec.se! dsee http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347253/ (actually your question is duplicate to this and many other similar :-) )

Comment: BTW, you are not supposed to use `tabularx` here since you do not have any `X` type column. You could simply define a smaller column `\newcolumntype{A}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.354cm}}` and then do `\begin{tabular}{|A|T|T|}` (and of course end the thing with `\end{tabular}`).

Comment: @Zarko Did you read the question? It is written "But the problem is that there is some unnecessary space in the first column." I am not sure if your answer helps with that. Am I missing something?

Comment: @marmot, i check my answer again. there is no unnecessary space. it seems that op like to have first column of  the `l` type (this has sense, if the text is short an in one column only. i suggest you that you write an answer and show this possibilities.

Comment: @Zarko I was interpreting this as a simple "The left column has to much space", which can be cured by making it smaller. And no, I do not intend to write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me extend my comment to an answer:

- you provide only code snippet  of table, so actual document layout is not known. therefore i use document with page borders determined by the `geometry package
- answer is based on my answer to question ["items list inside table cell are not well aligned"](http://%20tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347253).
- in comparison to it i made the following changes:

  - from your question i conclude, that in the cells of the first columns you have short one line text. for such text is appropriate to use the `l` column type
  - since you use the `tabularx` table environment with left aligned columns' headers, i accordingly change definitions of `I` column and command `mch`:

    ```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[showframe,
                a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

    % added packages and column definitions
    \usepackage{ragged2e}           % for smart align of cells' content

        \usepackage{enumitem}       % for nice list
    \newcolumntype{I}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash%            % <-- for lists in columns
                           \itemize}X<{\enditemize}}
    \newcommand\mch[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\small{#1}}}  % <-- for columns headers

    \begin{document}

        \begin{table}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
        \setlist[itemize]{nosep,        % <-- new list setup
                         leftmargin = *,
                         before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                         after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                         }
    \caption{The table caption}
        \label{tab:itemize}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ >{\RaggedRight}p{0.2\linewidth}  *{2}{I} }
        \toprule
    Column 1 & \mch{Column 2} & \mch{Column 3}                          \\
        \midrule
    Multiple column and column
        &   \item   multi line item text multi line item text multi line item text multi line item
      text multi line item text
            \item   x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
            &   \item   multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item
     text multiline item text
                \item   x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
    ```

[image]

in the case, that texts in the first column are longer and had to be broken into more lines, than instead of `l` column you should use `p{<width>` column type and determine its width according to your taste. in this case the columns `I` will adopt to the rest of the table width automatically. for example with

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ >{\RaggedRight}p{0.2\linewidth}  *{2}{I} }
```

you will obtain:

[image]

Comment: Hello, @Zarko, I have used "longtable" according to your answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347253/items-list-inside-table-cell-are-not-well-aligned. But problem is that my article is two column in which longtable not work. Is there any way to use supertabular/xtab with your code?

Comment: @BloodstoneProgrammer, i'm sorry, but i'm not familiar with this two packages. table is two column wide, so it has to be span over two columns with use `table*`. if table is to long for one page, than i would rather split it into two part where for the first i will use `[!b]` placement specifier and for the second `[!t]`.

Comment: @BloodstoneProgrammer: You can try to nest your longtable  in a `strip` environment from the `cuted` package (`ncctools` bundle) which leaves the two-column mode.

Comment: @Bernard, good idea. i forgot on this package :-(. thank you very much for the info.

Answer (score 3):

I propose this simpler code, based on `tabularx`, with a customised `itemize` environment in the last two columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{The table caption}
\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, itemsep=0pt, topsep=0pt, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, rightmargin=-\leftmargini}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=0.6\hsize}X|*{2}{>{\hsize=1.2\hsize\compress\arraybackslash}X|}}
\hline
Column 1 & Column2 & Column 3\\
\hline
Multiple column and column &
\begin{itemize}
 \item
multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item
  text multiline item text
\item
multiline item text multiline item text
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
\item
multiline item text multiline item text multiline item text multiline item
 text multiline item text
 \item
multiline item text multiline item text
\end{itemize}
 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]