# How to make a paragraph appear closer to the itemization than the preceeding paragraph?

Tags: spacing, itemize, paragraphs

```
We have done blah blah blah

Reasons:

\begin{itemize}
\item The need to blah blah
\item The problem of blah blah
\item \ldots
\end{itemize}
```

Results:

[image]

As you can see the single-word paragraph "Reasons" appears visually much closer to the preceeding paragraph than to the itemization, which looks wrong.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: How do I make this image smaller? Adding an `m` to the name of the .png as described here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165795/how-to-make-pictures-smaller doesn't work

Comment: [How to remove the whitespace BEFORE itemize/enumerate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86055/134144) might be helpful.

Comment: Load `enumitem` and use `\begin{itemize}[nosep]`.

Comment: That list is part of the preceding paragraph but you have inserted a paragraph space before the list