# Remove the spacing before the itemized list

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize

Anybody knows how I can remove the spacing before my itemized list?

```
\begin{document}   
 {\bf main text }\hfill{year}\\
    {title}\\
    \renewcommand\labelitemii{$\square$} 
    \begin{itemize}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0.05em}
    \item[$\square$] item 1
    \item[$\square$] item 2
    \item[$\square$] item 3
    \item[$\square$] item 4\\
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See either [How to remove the whitespace BEFORE `itemize`/`enumerate`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86054/5764) or [Vertical space in lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10684/5764).

Comment: why have you got `\\ ` before the list?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, removing the '\\' solved the issue in my case.

Comment: Regarding your usage of `\bf` you might want to take a look at: [“Correct” way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/134144)

Answer (score 3):

Never use `\\` at the end of a paragraph or before a display constrict such as a list or equation, TeX will warn about such use with a warning about `badness 10000` (it's maximum measure of bad typesetting) and produce a spurious extra line of the paragraph which looks like vertical space but is not space and does not combine with vertical space in a useful way.