# Vertical Space in lists - different spaces before and after list

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, itemize

Here at Stackexchange there are some questions related to vertical space in lists. For example:
[\topsep, \itemsep, \partopsep and \parsep - what does each of them mean (and what about the bottom)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300340/topsep-itemsep-partopsep-and-parsep-what-does-each-of-them-mean-and-wha)
[How to remove the whitespace BEFORE itemize/enumerate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86054/how-to-remove-the-whitespace-before-itemize-enumerate/485885#485885)

My question just goes a little bit further:

I'd like to modify the whitespace BEFORE the list WITHOUT modifying the space AFTER the list. If i just change the parameter \topsep, both whitespaces will change.
Ideally i want to change the parameters globally.

The only solution i found, is to include a negative vertical space before each list.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. See documentation for the `enumitem` package. There is on page 3 sketch with all "spaces" -- measures of lists. Documentation is part of `enumitem` installation or you can find on CTAN or by help of Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her is a simple solution with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate, 1]{before={\addtolength{\topsep}{1cm}}, after=\vspace*{-1cm}}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.Some text. Some text.
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First item \the\topsep
      \item Second item
      \item Third item
    \end{enumerate}
Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't realize, that this could be done with "before" and "after"

Comment: Only using enumitem.  You can do it without enumitem, but it wll take more lines.