# Use \textbullet\ in text like \item in itemize

Tags: tables, itemize, text

I am trying to use `\textbullet\` in a text like `\item` from the itemize environment. So far, I have come up with the code below. However, I do not want to use `\newline` at the beginning of my new command but need to have Tex jump to the next line after "my first bullet point" and "my second bullet point".

Please see my (ugly) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myitem}{\newline \textbullet~~} 

\begin{document}

Header
\myitem my first bullet point
\myitem my second bullet point  

\end{document}
```

**How would I have to rewrite my new command? Is there a solution for this?**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: why not use itemize? (it is not at all clear from your description what output you want)

Comment: What prevents you to use the itemize environment?

Comment: I want to use the items in a few table cells and the itemize environment takes up too much space. Do you think, it would be a better approach to modify the itemize environment instead?

Comment: "Jumping to the next line" can be done with `\par`.

Comment: What I want is the following: Within the itemize environment, you do not have to tell Tex to jump to the next line for a new item (using e.g. \\ or \newline) - it happens automatically. When using \textbullet\ within text, you do indeed have to tell Latex when to jump to a new line, otherwise the bullet point will be placed inline (which is of course usually what it is intended to do). I hope this clarifies a bit better what I need my command to do?

Comment: Perfect, using \par instead of \newline does indeed solve my problem! Thank you!

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/vertical-space-in-lists and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86054/how-to-remove-the-whitespace-before-itemize-enumerate.

Comment: the itemize enviornment can be custimized to take as little space as you need