# enumitem revert nolistsep

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem

With `enumitem` package, I have used `\setlist{nolistsep}` for some part of the document.  For another part of my document, I need to revert the separation in the list entries to its default.  I wonder how this can be done.

Comment: You could use `\begin{<list>}[nolistsep]` to localize the change.

Comment: Or vice versa: if most of your lists have `nolistsep` you can add an explicit `listsep` for that list.

Comment: I have added an explicit listsep for the part I needed.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Write it up (both sides).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `enumitem` package allows you to set list parameters both globally (via the `\setlist` command) and locally (via explicit parameters added to `\begin{<list>}`.

So if most of your lists require the compact format, you can use

```
\setlist{nosep}
```

(the `nolistsep` parameter has been deprecated, although still works).

If at a certain point in the document you want all subsequent lists to return to the default, you can issue a new `\setlist` command:

```
\setlist{}
```

will set the list parameters back to the default.

If only one specific list needs the default parameters, you can use:

```
\begin{<list>}[itemsep=4pt,parsep=4pt,topsep=8pt,partopsep=4pt]
```

or set specific values as needed.

Comment: From `enumitem` [documentation](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf): The key `nolistsep`, now deprecated, introduced a thin stretch, which was not the intended behavior