# How to control the space around items in enumerated list globally

Tags: environments, lists, enumerate

The second fully voted answer of ths [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6081/59624) suggest that to use `\itemsep0em`  for reduce the spaces between items locally. But how can I define it to be implemented for whole the document and for just the enumerate list. Here is my code sample:

```
 \documentclass[]{article}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}
            \item[a] $f=x^2-3y^2-8x+9y+3xy$
            \item[b] $f=x^2+4y^2-6x+16y$
            \item[c]$f=xy-x+y$
            \item[d] $f=\dfrac{5x^3}{3}+\dfrac{2}{3}y^3-\dfrac{15}{2}x^2+y^2-4y+7$
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{document}
```

and I want to set a certain value for the space between items globally.  Should it be like the following cod:

`\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\itemsep}{0pt}`

Sorry if the above code makes you annoyed.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: you are already loading (but not using) the enumitem package which gives declarations to set the global list parameters and an optional argument to set them per list, without ever needing to reference `\itemsep` and related lengths explicitly. see `texdoc enumitem`

Comment: Since you are using `enumitem` you can use `\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0pt,}`. You can include any other cusomizatiosn in the `setlist` and that will apply to _all_ `enumerate` lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also define a new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{my_enumerate}{
\begin{enumerate}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
\begin{my_enumerate}
    \item[a] $f=x^2-3y^2-8x+9y+3xy$
    \item[b] $f=x^2+4y^2-6x+16y$
    \item[c] $f=xy-x+y$
    \item[d] $f=\frac{5x^3}{3}+\frac{2}{3}y^3-\frac{15}{2}x^2+y^2-4y+7$
\end{my_enumerate}
\end{document}
```

If you need them even closer, you can use negative numbers, but be careful not to cause overlapping text.

Comment: Thnaks so much. Thank you for the time!