# Spacing between items containing a parbox

Tags: spacing, lists

I would like to make a list, each entry of which has two pieces of information: a date range, and a description. If there are two separate date ranges that apply to an item, I would like to be able to write

```
\begin{itemize}
  ...
  \item \parbox[t]{5cm}{date range 1\\ date range 2} description
  ...
\end{itemize}
```

However, the inter-item spacing seems to get thrown off by this; for example, when I compile

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \parbox[t]{5cm}{test\\test}
  \item test
  \item test
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

what I see is

[image]

The spacing between the first and second items is not the same as the spacing between the second and third items.

Is there a way of getting the spacing to be equal? I'd like to avoid if possible using a package like the ones described [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/825), since (I think) that would change the spacing in the rest of the list.

Also, I assume that there is a smarter way of creating the kind of list I'm describing than the method I am attempting - any suggestions regarding that are welcome too.

Comment: How long is the description you're talking about? If it extends over more than one line, the "regular itemize vertical gap" would be larger than `\baselineskip`, making the date range lines not match up with the description. Would you be able to update your MWE to include a little more detail showing some output possibilities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should end the \parbox with a \strut to give it normal depth ("test" doesn't contain chars with descender). Or use a tabular instead (each line in a tabular has a standard height).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \parbox[t]{5cm}{test\\test}
  \item test\\test
  \item test\\test
  \item \parbox[t]{5cm}{test\\test\strut}
  \item test\\test
  \item test\\test
  \item \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{5cm}}test\\test\end{tabular}
  \item test\\test
  \item test\\test

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The struts seem to do the trick. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

I think you'd be best with a modified description environment, something like

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\newenvironment{mydescription}
               {\list{}{\labelwidth5em 
                        \let\makelabel\mydescriptionlabel}}
               {\endlist}

\newcommand*\mydescriptionlabel[1]{%
                                \smash{\parbox[t]{5em}{\normalfont\bfseries #1}}}


\def\d{description description description goes here. }
\begin{document}
\begin{mydescription}
  \item [test 1\\test 2]  \d\d
  \item [test]\d\d\d
  \item [test]\d
\end{mydescription}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\smash` might be too much of a blunt instrument in practice, but it depends on what you want the behaviour to be if the label is bigger than the description and/or you are near a page break.

I think the following vesrsion would detect if the description paragraph was one line and if so add extra space for teh two line label

```
\newenvironment{mydescription}
               {\list{}{\labelwidth5em 
                        \let\item\myitem
                        \let\makelabel\mydescriptionlabel}}
               {\endlist}

\newcommand*\mydescriptionlabel[1]{%
                                \smash{\parbox[t]{5em}{\normalfont\bfseries #1}}}

\let\saveditem\item
\def\myitem{%
\relax\ifnum\prevgraf=1 \vskip\baselineskip\fi
\saveditem}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This seems like a good start, but as you mention in the last paragraph, I'd want the spacing to work with a two-line date even when the description is only one line (for example, `\item [test 1\\test 2]  \d` has incorrect spacing following it). Perhaps there's a way of pretending the description has the same height as the date range?

Comment: You could open up the whole thing by making it, say, `\labelwidth5em \itemsep\baselineskip` then there is always room for the 2 line label but if you want the tighter spacing, but essentially add a blank line after 1-line items, I'd need to remind myself how this is supposed to work... (or someone else may step in:-)

Comment: answer updated to cope with a short description